# Java Recursive function that determines if there are two consecutive numbers which are equal

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, range

I am quite confused about how to write this code recursively. I must create a method that determines if there are two consecutive numbers which are equal within a specific range on an array.

An example of an array that should return true would be: 3, 2, 2, 1
Where i=0 and j=3.

So far this is my code, but it does not implement the problem correctly.

```
private static boolean problem1(int[] arr, int i, int j)
    {
        int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, j+1); //Create a new array that only contains the specific given range

        for(int x = i; x < newArray.length; x++){ 
            int y = (x+1);
            if(newArray[x]==newArray[y]){
               return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: 1) Your solution is not recursive.  2) A proper solution does not need to copy the array.  3) A proper solution won't use a `for` or `while` loop.  The recursion will (in effect) do the looping.

Comment: This seems like a homework problem on recursion. Do you understand the principle of recursion? It seems like you're trying to tackle the problem with an iterative solution rather than a recursive one. Also, for what it's worth, note that in your loop if `x=newArray.length-1` and you set `y=x+1` then `newArray[y]` would be equivalent to doing `newArray[newArray.length]` and would give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone who commented, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static boolean problem1(int[] A, int i, int j) {
    if (A == null || A.length == 1 || A.length == 0 || i == j) {
        return false;
    }

    if (A[i] == A[i + 1]) {
        return true;
    }
    i++;
    return problem1(A, i, j);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the recursive function explanation in the code itself

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class RecurseFunc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        int[] arr = new int[]{3,2,2,1};
        int[] arr = new int[]{3,2,4,1,1};
//        System.out.println(problem1(arr,0,3));
//        System.out.println(problemRec(arr, 4,-1,0));
        System.out.println(problemRecWrapper(new int[]{-1,2,4,1,0}, 4,  0));
    }

    static boolean  problemRecWrapper(int[] arr, int arrLastIndex, int currentIndex) {
        return problemRec(new int[]{-1,2,4,1,0}, 4, -1, 0);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param arr      Complete array
     * @param arrLastIndex - Starting index point
     * @param lastIndex - Last element index
     * @param currentIndex - Current arr index
     * @return
     */
    static boolean  problemRec(int[] arr, int arrLastIndex, int lastIndex, int currentIndex) {
        if(currentIndex > arrLastIndex) {
            return false;
        }
        if(lastIndex > 0 && arr[lastIndex] == arr[currentIndex]) {
            return true;
        }
        currentIndex++;
        return problemRec(arr, arrLastIndex,lastIndex,currentIndex);

    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, you seem to be using the variables `i` and `j` differently from the original question. Also, there's no need for the "last element" param, you can just compare your current element to the next element. Your current method would actually incorrectly return `true` if the input array had a `-1` at the starting index even if it didn't actually have any two same elements.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @MihirKekkar > I tried to refactor my variable names to the names originally used in the Q but now updated my code to use some meaningful names.

Comment: there's still the issue that if I call `problemRec(new int[]{-1,2,4,1,0}, 4, -1, 0)` it returns true when there's no consecutive equal numbers in that array.

Comment: @MihirKekkar Fixed the code. I hope you don't expect more validations around user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean problem1(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 1 || arr.length == 0 || i == j) {
        return false;
    }

    if (arr[i] == arr[j])
        return true;

    i++;
    return problem1(arr, i, j);

}
```

Comment: `i` and `j` may not be required but they make the solution far more efficient. Your method is copying over the entire array each time, and simply using `int` indices rather than calling `Arrays.copyOfRange` each time would be more efficient for large inputs.